# GOOGLE SHEET COUNTIF PARSE ERROR IN DATA ANALYTICS COURSE BY GOOGLE

Tags: google-sheets

=COUNTIF(‘raw data’!G:G,A2)
THIS IS THE CODE, CAN ANYONE HELP ME FIND WHERE I AM WRONG.

Comment: Using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is pretty rude to do to people you want to help you. So, please rewrite your question and use normal capitalization. Also, please be more specific and detailed, provide a [mre], explain the problem, ask an actual question and make sure to include the error message.

Comment: Sorry about the all caps , I didn't knew about that and thankyou for explaining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`‘ ’` <- are different with `'`. How About this? `=COUNTIF('raw data'!G:G,A2)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you or anyone else that needs the answer.
Look at the name of your sheet (the sheet that you are trying to extract the information from) - if it is not named raw data - make sure you either name it raw data - or use its name inside quotation marks to solve the equation :)